# g++ fatal error no input file on codeblocks ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, build, codeblocks

I am new to codeblocks and getting following error when trying to build.

`g++ fatal error no input file`

Not sure what it means. I try to set the execution dir in project properties but didnt worked and I am stuck with this error. Can anyone help please.

Comment: It means you have no source file.

Comment: Have you added source files to the codeblocks project?

Comment: Hi, there is main.cpp with the main() function, is there anything extra I need to do here?

Answer (score -1):

What type of project did u create?

Create a project like this

`File->New->Project` and select `Console Application` template